# Javafx in swing component resize

Tags: javafx, jdialog

i am creating a basic javafx in swing application where i added some component and resize is working ok for them then i have added a `jdialog` on a button when i  open and close jdialog for work my application loose resize.

here is code for jdialog

```
jd=new JDialog();
      jd.add(createJpanelForSelection(data));
      jd.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500,400));
      jd.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
      jd.show();
```

following are two images before and after opening jdialog

[image: before opening jdialog]

[image: after jdialog]

if i am working on application in full screen size then it don't appear but if size is less than full screen view than after jdialog it lost resizing

Answer (score -1):

Did you try:

```
jd.setSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
jd.setResizable(false);
```

Comment: i tried not working. and its appear only after jdialog

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: If the component is not controlled by a layout manager, you can set its size by invoking the setSize or setBounds method on it. You need to provide size hints and then make sure you are using a layout manager that respects the size hints.